# Where does the name "tracking type problem" come from?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, optimization, optimal-control, constraints

In PDE-constrained optimization problems, the distributed control problem

$$ \begin{array}{ll} 
\displaystyle \min_{y,u} & J(y,u) = \frac{1}{2}\|y-y_d\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 + \frac{\alpha}{2}\|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 \\
\text{subject to} & \mathcal{D}y = u, \quad \text{on}\ \Omega, \\
& \phantom{\mathcal{D}}y = g, \quad \text{in}\ \partial\Omega,
\end{array} $$

where $ y $ is the state, $ u $ the control, $ y_d $ the desired state, and  $ \mathcal{D} $ is some differential operator, e.g. $ \mathcal{D} = \Delta $, is in literature often referred to as *tracking type problems*.

So my question is:

> Where does this name come from? What is the origin of the name?

---

**Edit**: So I have found now in the book [Numerical PDE-constrained optimization](https://books.google.dk/books?id=hi6SBgAAQBAJ) that the *tracking*-name appear to be linked to the cost functional $ J $. Here Juan de los Reyes writes that "Quadratic objective functionals like $ J(y,u) $ are known as *tracking type* costs." I note that his cost function only differs in the term $ \|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 $, where he has $ \|u\|_{L^2(\Gamma)}^2 $, where $ \Gamma = \partial\Omega $ the the boundary of the domain. This is due to his problem being formulated with a Neumann boundary condition.

This does not answer the question though.

Comment: Is there some motivation for this question that might help in formulating an answer, or at least a reference for a possible answer?

Comment: @Achaire: I am not certain what you mean, but an example of a place it is used is here: https://kar.kent.ac.uk/48153/1/Pearson_Thesis.pdf ( page 6 just above eq (2.2) )

Comment: If $u$ is the input and $y$ is the output, then we want $y$ to **track** a given desired output $y_d$, which is why we minimize the tracking error $\|y-y_d\|$. However, we do not want to make $u$ too large either, which is why we also minimize the input energy $\|u\|$. This is an LQR problem ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-quadratic_regulator )

Answer (score 1):

The quadratic objective function $J(y,u)$ will have lesser and lesser value when $Y$ approach $y_{\rm d}$ and will have an optimal value or least value with respect to the first term when $y=y_{\rm d}$. The cost function,  $J(y,u)$ will remain to be optimal if $y$ remains to be equal to  $y_{\rm d}$ or in other words if $y$ tracks or follows the value of $y_{\rm d}$. All these terms should be in terms of time to make more sense I guess, I mean function such as $y(t)$,$y_{\rm d}(t)$. So optimization problem with such an objective function is equivalent to tracking control problem.